# How to create a class without constructor parameter which has dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, parameter-passing

I have added the dependency injections to the project. But when i create an instance by using ***new*** keyword, dependency injection doesn't work.

```
public class MyClass
{
    ILoginTokenKeyApi _loginTokenKeyApi;

    public MyClass(ILoginTokenKeyApi loginTokenKeyApi)
    {
        _loginTokenKeyApi = loginTokenKeyApi;
    }

    ...
}
```

When i try to create an instance of MyClass, it wants a parameter to be constructed naturally.

Just like this :

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass(); // ERROR, it wants a parameter (but it is what i want)
```

I have to do :

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass(new LoginTokenKeyClass()); // this is not a good code for me
```

How i create an instance of MyClass without parameter because it has dependency injected.

Comment: Did you try registering ILoginTokenKeyApi with your dependency injection? It usually should be able to automatically insert the parameters into the constructor. Otherwise if you really want to create an instance without the ILoginTokenKeyApi object, see the answer about property injection. If you are needing this in the context of unit tests, you should probably look into mocking frameworks like moq.

Comment: @vasily.sib // I have edited this post a bit, please check it again.

Comment: What IoC container are you using?

Comment: Well, when you are on Dependency Injection, normally you don't create an instances by your self. It is responsability of DI container. Just for example, with Ninject you create an instance like this: `var instance = _kernel.Get<MyClass>();`.

Comment: Please help us to help you. Your question is very unclear, possibly because you misunderstood Dependency Injection. To help us, can you please read this freely available [introductory chapter](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/6/8e7ceae-8328-4e4a-b9a0-ba97d4d4cb30/Seemann2_DEidotNET2E_MEAP_V12_ch1.pdf) of [this book](https://manning.com/seemann2) on Dependency Injection. And can you reformulate your question after reading that chapter?

Answer (score 11):

> But when i create an instance by using `new` keyword, dependency injection doesn't work.

That’s fundamentally how dependency injection works.

With dependency injection, you are simply not supposed to `new` up new objects. That’s the whole point of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). Instead of creating objects and managing those objects’ dependencies, you are depending on the framework to *give* you the dependencies *you* need without having you to care about where they actually come from and how *they* are constructed properly. So you are moving the responsibility to create the object up to the caller.

If you find yourself in need to create an object that has a dependency, then this is a clear sign that you are doing it wrong. A common reason for this is that you want to create the object in order to manage its lifetime, or because it is actually a data object that just happens to have some operations that needs other dependencies to work (e.g. an entity that has a “save” method). In the first case, you simply don’t do it like that. You just depend on it and let the framework manage the lifetime; if it has an incorrect lifetime, then you should reconfigure it with the DI container.

In the latter case where you have a data object with operations, you should split this up. You should just have a data object, without any logic, and then inject some manager service that is able to perform the operation on that data object for you.

For example in ASP.NET Core Identity, you have the `User` object which is just a normal entity without any logic. In order to e.g. add user roles or change the password, you rely on the user manager which you can inject. So the `User` object itself is without any dependencies.

I’d generally suggest you to read the [dependency injection chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) of the ASP.NET Core documentation to understand how dependency injection works and how it is supposed to be used within the framework.

Comment: "With dependency injection, you are simply not supposed to new up new objects.". I understand what you are trying to say here, but this is not completely accurate. It is completely _fine_ to `new` up dependencies, as long as you do this inside the start-up path of your application, a.k.a. the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). DI does not require the use of a DI Container, a practice commonly referred to as [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di//). Apart from that, I agree with you.

Comment: @Steven Sure, in that case, that would be perfectly fine. From the context of the question, this is ASP.NET Core which does have a (mandatory) DI container and as such OP is attempting to do that within a dependency (since you simply don’t have access to the composition root like that). – But yeah, your comment is completely valid although I do think that it goes a bit too deep considering OP’s atttempts :)

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding that using a DI Container is mandatory in ASP.NET Core. This is not the case.

Comment: @Steven I’d be interested to see how to set it up without a DI container when the full framework uses dependency injection to compose its components. But I honestly doubt that you will be able to do this without a container unless you are talking about composing hundreds of (internal) dependencies manually.

Comment: Chapter 7.3 of [my book](https://manning.com/seemann2) actually describes in detail how to apply [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di//) in ASP.NET Core. You can see a short demonstration in [this repository](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/tree/master/src/SampleApplication.PureDI). When to choose a DI Container over Pure DI, however, is a more complicated question. This is something that is discussed in chapter 12.

Comment: @Steven Sorry, but no, that is not an example of ASP.NET Core without a dependency injection container. Yes, you are avoiding the existing container for your own (two) components but the project is still using the default DI container and you are in fact using it in order to set up your `CompositionRoot` as well. – So if that’s your example, then I’ll have to stand by my point that you cannot really use ASP.NET Core practically without a DI container.

Comment: even though the ASP.NET Core framework might use something that _resembles_ a container (I typically refer to that thing as  "the configuration system"), you are not required to use it to _build up your application components_, and this is actually important. The choice between using a DI Container or Pure DI must be consciously made, especially because that built-in "configuration system" is really limited. Practicing Pure DI has many advantages, even when the framework uses reflection to build its internal components.

Comment: @Steven Unless you reconfigure it, the framework will use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection which **is** a DI container. – In any way, this discussion is derailing quite a bit now and is no longer relevant to the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not clear what you trying to achieve, but in order to do DI in .Net Core you have to create an interface IMyClass, then let your class implement that interface,

```
public interface IMyClass {
   void SampleMethod();
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    ILoginTokenKeyApi _loginTokenKeyApi;

    public MyClass(ILoginTokenKeyApi loginTokenKeyApi)
    {
        _loginTokenKeyApi = loginTokenKeyApi;
    }

    public void SampleMethod()
    {
        // method logic goes here...
        var xx = _loginTokenKeyApi.WhatEver;
    }
}
```

then register ILoginTokenProvider and IMyClass in startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<ILoginTokenProvider, LoginTokenProvider>();
services.AddTransient<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

finally inject IMyClass where you need it:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel {

    private readonly IMyClass _myClass;

    public IndexModel(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        _myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
       _myClass.SampleMethod();
    }
}
```

btw, it is also possible to register and inject MyClass without implementing IMyClass interface, but I prefer to follow basic programming principals :)

Comment: You are not required to create and implement interfaces in order to use dependency injection properly. Switching to interfaces will not help OP in what they are trying to achieve, which is creating an object with `new` while having the dependencies resolved automatically. That just doesn’t work with dependency injection.

Comment: @poke, I already mentioned that creating interface is not necessary for DI, but the question itself was not clear enough to explain the problem, so I tried to offer a possible solution.

Comment: Well, creating an interface for every class (even in DI) is not a programming principal. You can implement abstraction in DI and that's the only case you should use interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Dependency Injections.

1. Constructor Injection - which you dont want
2. Property Injection - In this - you expose Public Get/Set property of the Object you want to be injected. And then in your DI config file (like spring.net) you can assign values.

Another way you can do DepInjection is that in the param less constructor - you can get the Object by a Key/Name. Like in Spring.Net we would do:

```
var UtilityObject = Spring.ContextRegistry.GetContext().GetObject("MyUtilObject") as TheUtilityClass;
```

Comment: Not my downvote but this answer does not cover the fundamendal issue OP has when attempting to use dependency injection. Property injection will not solve this at all, and even with property injection you will _not_ be able to `new` up an object (which is what OP wants to do).

Comment: @poke - Our Answer/Post is for the first version of the Question that OP posted. The question has been modified. Also, OP can remove the Constructor Injection (add Param Less constructor) - that will allow him to new up the object. Also, as I advised they can add GetObject() call for fetching the Dependency.